# Unity move towards mouse position for limited distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a top-down 2D game project. The character must follow the mouse cursor all the time, this is what I could do so far. I also want the character to slide towards the mouse for a limited distance when clicked.

So let's say the character position is: 0, 0, 0
Mouse click position: 8, 4, 0
When clicked, the character must move towards the mouse click position but only for a limited distance, so it must not reach if distance more than 2. So the final character location should be: 2, 2, 0

How can I achieve that? Here is my code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovemetn : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 4;
    private float slideSpeed = 8;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private bool isMoving = false;

    void Update()
    {
        SetTargetPosition();

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            //Slide 2 meters towards mouse location (with the speed of slideSpeed variable)
        }
        
        if (isMoving)
        {
            Move();
        }

        
    }

    void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        targetPosition.z = transform.position.z;

        isMoving = true;
    }

    void Move()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
        {
            isMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I guess is that you constantly update the targetPosition as long as you hold the mouse button down. This would make it pretty hard to tell from which start point you actually want to allow maximum distance and when exactly you allow a new range.

I would assume you allow to move around in a range of `maxDistance` around an `_originalPosition` your object had the moment the mouse went down.

Then you can use [`Vector2.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html) to calculate a range around that stored `_originalPosition` like

```
// For 2D use Vector2 right away
private Vector2 targetPosition;

[SerializeField] private float maxDistance;

private void Update()
{
    // Only update the target for the first click position
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        SetTargetPosition()
    }

    if (isMoving)
    {
        Move();
    }
}

void SetTargetPosition()
{
    // as before get your target position
    var tempTargetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    // Calculate a delta vector _originalPosition -> tempTargetPosition
    // then make sure its magnitude is maximum maxDistance
    var delta = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(tempTargetPosition - transform.position, maxDistance);

    // Calculate and update the actual target position
    targetPosition = transform.position + delta;

    isMoving = true;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that helped a lot, especially the SetTargetPosition part. Thanks. Now the only problem is that I need to click and hold the mouse until it arrives at maxDistance. I want it to go to the maxDistance when I click only once

Comment: @UNEX oh in that case I understood wrong and you can just remove the `GetMouseButtonUp` block

Comment: @UNEX so just to confirm: Do you want `SetTargetPosition` be updated continously or did you also want that only for the first click position?

Comment: Ok, removing the GetMouseButtonUp block solved the problem. The solution you provided was exactly what I was looking for, now it works like I wished, thanks a lot...

Comment: @UNEX Glad to help then! I already thought I made it more complicated than necessary ^^

Comment: One last thing... Can you also tell me how can I SetTargetPosition only for the first click position and not be updated until it arrives, as you mentioned in the previous comment ^^

Comment: @UNEX oh in that case I actually made it more complicated than necessary :'D see update

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the delta distance and its vector between Origin and your Destination.
After normalizing those values, you could multiply them with some kind of 'base distance' for example in this case your (2, 2, 0) and add/subtract it from your destination, something like that should do the trick:

```
var delta = (Destination - origin).normalized;
delta *= baseDistance;
var targetDestination = Destination - delta;
```

But keep in mind that (0,2,0) is closer than (2,2,0), so you might want to adept that calculation